# Python to executable - unable to import modules

Tags: python, exe

Running Python 3.5 on Win10 x64. Have tried py2exe, PyInstaller and cxfreeze. All of them run and generate an .exe. But none of the .exes run with all of them immediately closing after an error. All of them have warning logs with a huge list of required modules that couldn't be imported properly.

PyInstaller:

```
missing module named time.time - imported by time, http.cookies
...
missing module named urllib.proxy_bypass - imported by urllib, requests.compat 
...
```

cxfreeze:

```
Missing modules:

    ? Cookie imported from requests.compat
    ? Image imported from openpyxl.drawing.image
    ? OpenSSL.SSL imported from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
    ? StringIO imported from requests.compat, requests.packages.urllib3.packages.six
    ...
```

PyInstaller also throws dependancy errors such as "api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll" missing. I have Visual C++ 2005-2015 all installed with Visual Studio Community 15 installed too.

Comment: I have some experience with **py2exe**. Can you tell me what errors you faced with that?

Comment: @CrakC I think for py2exe, it didn't support python 3.5 as it kept trying to open a 3.4 version file. Also, when installing (not via pip), it asked me to point to my python 3.4 directory and quit when it didn't find one

Comment: Also, Win10 is a new OS and compatibility issues are quite obvious in this case. Do you have a problem in moving from 3.5 to 3.4?

Comment: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '...Python\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\py2exe\\run-py3.5-win-amd64.exe' ` this is the specific error. At that location, only a run-py3.4 exists

Comment: @CrakC I don't know if I have a problem moving to 3.4 - what could be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
PyInstaller 3.0  Python 3.5 on Win10 x64 with Visual Studio Community 15 
works for me. I run pyinstaller --onefile file_script.py
    in windows path i have the folowing
    C:\Python35;
    C:\Python35\Scripts;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin;
```

Comment: Immediately I notice that I don't have Python installed to C root (I like to keep that clean!), do you think that could be causing problems, where scripts are trying to find files relative to where they are?

Comment: @Prof, yes, it well could be just that.

Comment: Do you know of a painless way on changing install directory? I assume uninstalling and reinstalling would lose me all my custom modules?

Comment: @Prof you can  move python folder whenever you want, but you need to update windows PATH in system properties.

Comment: Still getting the same errors after moving and changing PATH. Just to clarify, what I'm doing is pulling up a command line and typing:  `python -m PyInstaller --onefile 123.py`

Comment: Also a script like `print("hello world")` has the dependancy errors when building the exe and still has the missing module warnings BUT the .exe does run properly.

Comment: hey could it be possible for you to show me how you bundle your data files in for a script that has imports (from 3rd party modules etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this is an issue with openpyxl which was a module being imported.

https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/498/moving-constants-to-a-configuration-file
https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/pull-requests/67/include-constantsjson-as-part-of-the/diff
https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/pull-requests/83/use-__about__py-instead-of-constantsjson/diff

Downloading a copy of the repository, using the changes made in the last URL and then installing openpyxl from that (using `pip install -e (openpyxldirectory) allows a working .exe to be generated